# How to send an e-mail after adding the product to the cart in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, email

Unfortunately, so far I am a complete beginner in creating a module in Magento.
I need to send an email after adding the item to the cart.

As I understand it, I need to use the checkout_cart_product_add_after event

I created some files, but I don't understand how to send an email after adding the item to the cart

My/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="email_after_adding_product" instance="My\Module\Observer\SendEmailForCart"/>
</event>
```

My/Module/Observer/SendEmailForCart.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use My\Module\Helper\Email;

class SendEmailForCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $helperEmail;

    public function __construct(
        Email $helperEmail
    ) {
        $this->helperEmail = $helperEmail;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        return $this->helperEmail->sendEmail();
    }
}
```

My/Module/Helper/Email.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Helper;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    public function __construct(

    )
    {

    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        try {
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Please tell, what code I need to write in the Email.php file?
And do I need to create any additional files or modify the ones I showed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Code for sending email is this one :

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;

class ClassName implements ObserverInterface
{
   protected $storeManager;
   protected $_transportBuilder;
   protected $inlineTranslation;

   public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $smi,TransportBuilder $tb,StateInterface $si)
   {        
       $this->storeManager=$smi;
       $this->_transportBuilder=$tb;
       $this->inlineTranslation=$si;
   }

   public function yourFunctionName()
   {
       $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $templateVars = array(
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'customer_name' => $cname,
            'message'   => 'YOUR MESSAGE TEXT'
        );
        $from = array('email' => "SENDEREMAILADDRESS", 'name' => 'SENDERNAME');
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $to = array('RECEIVEREMAILADDRESS');
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('order_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
   } 
}
```

**NOTE** : we use `order_template` in the above code for the testing. you need to repalce that with your real template.

Answer (score 0):

In the Email.php file, you need to implement the logic for sending the email.

```
<?php
 namespace My\Module\Helper;

 use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
 use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
 use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Email extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_escaper;
    protected $_storeManager;

   public function __construct(
      Context $context,
      TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
      Escaper $escaper,
      StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
   ) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function sendEmail()
{
    $sender = [
        'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml('Sender Name'),
        'email' => 'sender@example.com'
    ];

    $recipientEmail = 'recipient@example.com';
    $recipientName = 'Recipient Name';

    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
        ->setTemplateIdentifier('my_email_template') // Change this to your email template ID
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
        ->setTemplateVars(['data' => 'Additional Data']) // Add any additional data you want to pass to the email template
        ->setFrom($sender)
        ->addTo($recipientEmail, $recipientName)
        ->getTransport();

    try {
        $transport->sendMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
}
```

Make sure to replace Sender Name, sender@example.com, recipient@example.com, and Recipient Name with appropriate values. Also, replace my_email_template with the ID of your email template.