# How to send email with attachment using object manager programmatically

Tags: magento2

I want to send an email using my custom PHP file in Magento root with an attachment using object manager. Please suggest to me what I do about it.

Comment: maybe this could help
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344365/how-to-send-an-e-mail-after-adding-the-product-to-the-cart-in-magento-2

Comment: Which Magento version you have used?

Answer (score 0):

**We use Mageplaza Magento 2 SMTP Module** [Click here to download and install](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/).

```
$emailSendStaus = 0;
try {
    /* Email and Password */
    $senderEmail = $username = "test@gamil.com";
    $password = "PASSWORD";
    $senderName = "TESTING";

    /* Sender Detils */

    /* Subject Name */
    $subject = "Test Email";

    /* HTML Body */
     $htmlBody = "<h1>TEST EMAIL</h1>";

    // SMTP Configuration
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;
    $smtpHost = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('smtp/configuration_option/host', $storeScope);
    $auth = strtolower($objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('smtp/configuration_option/authentication', $storeScope));
    $smtpConf = [];
    $smtpConf['auth'] = $auth;
    $smtpConf['username'] = $senderEmail;
    $smtpConf['password'] = $password;
    $smtpConf['port'] = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('smtp/configuration_option/port', $storeScope);
    $ssl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('smtp/configuration_option/protocol', $storeScope);
    if ($ssl != 'none') {
        $smtpConf['ssl'] = $ssl;
    }
    $smtpConfig = new \Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($smtpHost, $smtpConf);

    /* Email Start code */
    $mail = new \Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $senderName);
    $mail->addTo("sendeemailto@gamil.com", "Test");
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $mail->setBodyHtml($htmlBody);
    $fileContent = file_get_contents("http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf");
    $fileName = "pdf-test.pdf";
    $mail->createAttachment(
        $fileContent,
        \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $fileName
    );
    $mail->send($smtpConfig);
    /* Email Over code */
    $emailSendStaus = 1;
    echo "EMAIL SEND";
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```